# Dictionary using 2 keys with easy to find maximum value?

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to python and I need advice on figuring out how to implement this.  I'm not sure what the best structure to use would be.

I need a dictionary type structure that has 2 keys for a value.  I need retrieve the value with both keys, but delete the value by either key.  I also need to be able to find the maximum value and return the key (or a list of keys if there are duplicate maximums)

Basically this is for finding the longest distance between any 2 points on a graph.  I will have a list of points and I can calculate all the distances, but at any time I need to get the maximum distance and which points it connects. Any point can be removed at any time so I need to be able to remove values that connect to those points.

Obviously there is no existing structure that does this so i'll have to write my own class but does anyone have advise where to start?  At first I was going to use a dictionary with a tuple key, but is there a fast way to find the maximum value and also get the key (or list of keys - with the possibility of duplicate values).  Also how can I easily delete values by a single part of the tuple?

I'm not asking for anyone to solve this for me, I'm trying to learn, but any advice would help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sure there are already python libraries available that provide you with efficient structures for graphs.

Comment: What is the relationship between the keys? Composite, Synonyms, Primary / Secondary ?

Comment: If you want to work with graph, try [NetworkX](http://networkx.github.com/)

Comment: @Abhijit The keys are the 2 endpoints of the line, the value is the distance between them. I'm not sure what kind of relationship that would be.

Comment: I think OOP will help you to solve. Start with the class, split up your prob step by step.

Comment: @trashrobber Perhaps this might be useful http://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs/